# Canvas width and height calculation is off

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, height, width

I'm using some script I found on Git that generates a snow effect. Somewhere in the code I have to set the width and the height of the canvas in which the snow is generated. I'm setting the canvas to the window full width / height :

```
canvas.width = $(window).width();
canvas.height = $(window).height();
```

But when rendered in the browser there are on both height and width some extra pixels adding scrollbars to the window. You can see the behavior here : [Canvas](http://disneyquet.com/) ; I'm not quite sure why the width / height is calculated wrong or if there's something else interfering with those calculations that it makes it bigger than the actual window width / height. Maybe someone has a different view of the behavior or encountered it before ?

Comment: Add the style property `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` element. That should solve your problem.

Comment: have you tried `$(window).outerWidth();` just to see if that gives the same size or not?

Comment: @AaditMShah ~ I need the overflow :) The content that will fill in the page will be bigger than the height of the window in most cases

Comment: @SmokeyPHP ~ same result with `outerHeight / Width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canvas` element is displayed inline by default, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849923/still-have-space-after-margin-padding-border-all-zero) about similar problem.

The solution is quite simple :) Add following css code to the canvas element:
`display: block;`
and scrollbars should disappear.

---

old answer:
`$(window).width()` works properly but i don't know why `$(window).height()` returns too large value. It cause also showing vertical scrollbar because earlier computed width don't include the size of horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? You're asking more questions instead of answering, sound more of an rhetorical answer :)

Comment: I still play with it and trying figure out the answer :)
just something cause that height is larger by 15px in my browser that is actually is...

Comment: @Roland, could you provide the feedback if my solution works for you, look at edited answer.

Comment: It does work :) I tried positioning and overflow ( which also worked ) but I don't really like hacks :) Thanks for the solution :)